# Flex 3: Adding a sprite to a Container's "rawChildren" sometimes adds it to the content children instead

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

The basic problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a mix of Flex & Flash components, and I have a generic function for adding a progress spinner to the component regardless. So if the component is a `Container`, I add it to the `rawChildren`, otherwise add it normally.

However, I'm running into a problem with a component that inherits from VBox. I call

```
cont.rawChildren.addChildAt(spinner, cont.rawChildren.numChildren);
```

But when I trace the children, my spinner shows up in `cont.getChildren()`, and the `comp.numChildren` obviously also increases by one. And other containers seem to work properly, even other VBox controls.

I walked through the Flex framework code and I can't find anything to explain why this would happen, either via inheritance or timing.

Has anyone seen anything similar or can explain why `rawChildren` might not be predictable in this case?

Thanks.

---

Function:

```
var bcu:Number = u.numChildren;
var bce:Number = el.numChildren;

el.addChildAt(s, ((pos > -1)?pos : el.numChildren));
trace("ADD NEW SPINNER", u, el, el.numChildren, u.numChildren, bce, bcu);
```

Where `el` is either the DisplayObject or the rawChildren object of a container, and `u` is the original object the spinner is being attached to.

Output:

```
ADD NEW SPINNER BlockMovePopup1734 [object ContainerRawChildrenList] 6 5 5 4
```

And then:

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion 
failed: cannot convert com.misc::SbSpinner@57970a1 to mx.core.IUIComponent.
```

The output shows that `el` is correctly set to `ContainerRawChildrenList` (the `rawChildren` object for the `VBox`) and that the `numChildren` is `[6,5]` vs `[5,4]` prior to the call. This means the `Sprite` is being added to the content children rather than to the rawChildren.

Comment: Which "content children" are you talking about? 
You say "However, I'm running into a problem with a component that inherits from VBox" but you don't explain exactly what happens with your class that extends from VBox.

Comment: "Content children" are the normal children of a container, not including the things like skins that are added to the rawChildren. My extended VBox is essentially just a popup/tooltip type thing, but does nothing special with the children. It contains up to 4 LinkButtons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was fun. Found the quirk. I think maybe the `rawChildren.addChildAt` function is a bit buggy. Found this block of text in the Container class:

> ```
>     Container assumes that content children are contiguous, and that
>     non-content children come before or after the content children.
>     In order words, Container partitions DisplayObjectContainer's
>     index range into three parts:
>
>     A B C D E F G H I
>     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    <- index for all children
>           0 1 2 3        <- index for content children
>
>     The content partition contains the content children D E F G.
>     The pre-content partition contains the non-content children
>     A B C that always stay before the content children.
>     The post-content partition contains the non-content children
>     H I that always stay after the content children.
> ```

If I used `rawChildren.addChild` it works fine for now. In both cases, the spinner was being added as the last child, but addChild does it correctly.

Comment: wow, good to know. This is TERRIBLE though for a platform... no wonder Flex is going down the drain these days for HTML5.